# Creating a Java desktop shortcut does not work

Tags: java, shortcut-file, jfugue

I have a Java program which runs just fine. Now I want to create a desktop shortcut. I don't create it in the *Desktop* folder, but that isn't a problem; I can create it in any folder.

I'm doing it right how I should do:

- Right-click in the folder
- choose "New" and "Shortcut"
- As destination, I choose the directory of the class file
- `C:\Users\%Path%\bin\Musikliste.class`
- Then I right-click it and choose the properties (I think it's called like that; my computer does show everything in German and there it's called "Eigenschaften").
- In "destination", I choose the path of *java.exe* and then the class name:
- `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-18\bin\java.exe" Musikliste`
- In "execute with", I choose the class path without the class:
- `C:\Users\%Path%\bin`
- Then it should work just fine.

If the program has only one class and no JFugue library, it works just fine. I tested it. But if the program contains several classes and the JFugue library, the shortcut to the main class does not work; when I run it, it prints several errors:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfugue/pattern/PatternProducer
    at Musikliste.lambda$4(Musikliste.java:63)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6616)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3398)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6381)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2266)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4991)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2324)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4823)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4948)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4516)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2310)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2780)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4823)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:775)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:720)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:97)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:747)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jfugue.pattern.PatternProducer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 36 more
```

Does it fail because it uses other classes? Or is it because of the imported library JFugue? Or something else?

I tested the whole process on another program running with only one class and not implementing external libraries. There it worked just fine. But on my other project, it does not. Why?

Comment: do you understand what "ClassNotFoundException" means?

Comment: Yeah, now I noticed the path was not valid anymore because I moved the directory to another path. I corrected it. But it still does not work. For some reason, if I go into the properties and choose Add jar, it does not find my .jar so I need to choose Add external jar and then find the place where it is. And I placed the jar in a new created lib-directory which is in the same directory as the bin-directory, as well as in the directory where the bin-directory is in. In both cases, Add jar does not find the external jar. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: Make sure all the libs you are using are being added to the classpath

Comment: You mean like `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/Users/%Path%/lib/jfugue-5.0.9.jar"/>`? Already done, long ago.

Comment: You need it added to your shortcut, not your development environment.

Comment: On Windows, presumably?